# Using nesting variable inside a function

Tags: r, nested, purrr

Is it possible to use a nesting variable inside a function used in `purrr::map`?
For example, in the following example I want each plot to have a title showing the number of cylinders

```
    library(tidyverse)
    plot_mtcars <- function(df, cyl){
                ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg), data = df) + 
                        geom_point() +
                        ggtitle(paste("Cylinders =", cyl))
            }
    plots <- mtcars %>% 
                nest(-cyl) %>% 
                mutate(plot = map(data, ~plot_mtcars(., cyl)))
```

The code above does not work, as all plots return:
`Cylinders = 6` 
(instead of 6,4,8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `cyl` is a vector, so it's setting a character vector in `ggtitle`, in which case only the first element is used; You need to loop through `cyl` and pass the corresponding element to the plot function:

```
plots <- mtcars %>% 
    nest(-cyl) %>% 
    # here use map2 to pass data and corresponding cyl to the plot function
    mutate(plot = map2(data, cyl, ~ plot_mtcars(.x, .y)))
```

Check the plot title:

```
plots$plot[[1]]$labels$title
# [1] "Cylinders = 6"

plots$plot[[2]]$labels$title
# [1] "Cylinders = 4"

plots$plot[[3]]$labels$title
# [1] "Cylinders = 8"
```

Comment: What if nesting is done using 2 variables and  I want to include both in the title. For example, plots <- mtcars %>%  nest(-cyl, -am) %>% mutate(plot = map2...

Comment: Do you need to access both `cyl` and `am` in the plot function ? In which case you might use `pmap` something like `pmap(list(data, cyl, am), ~ plot_mtcars(..1, ..2, ..3))` and your `plot_mtcars` function need to access three parameters as well.